# Nuxt - Taiwind | Applying hover classes programatically does not work on build

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, nuxt3

I'm using a nuxt3 project, with tailwind css. I'm using @nuxtjs/tailwind module to use tailwind.

I have a component button, and a mapping file, which specify the color button depending on a constant passed to him. Here is the relevant code for the button

```
import { toRefs } from 'vue';
import { Button, ButtonColorStyles, ColorEnum } from '@/typings';
import { BUTTON_COLOR_STYLES_CONSTANT } from '@/typings/constants';

const props = defineProps<{ content: Button }>();
const { content } = toRefs<{ content: Button }>(props);

const classes: string[] = [];

if (content.value.color) {
    const color: ColorEnum = content.value.color;
    const colors: ButtonColorStyles = BUTTON_COLOR_STYLES_CONSTANT[color];

    classes.push('bg-' + colors.backgroundColor);
    classes.push('text-' + colors.textColor);
    classes.push('hover:bg-' + colors.hoverBackgroundColor);
    classes.push('hover:text-' + colors.hoverTextColor);

    if (content.value.hasOutline) {
        classes.push('border');
        classes.push('border-gray-900');
    }
}
```

however, there some colors and hover classes that are not used elsewhere in the app, so they're not seen by tailwind on build.

I tried placing the in safelist option, it does not work (especially for the hover: classes). I tried directly, and with the variant stuff. None worked out.

see my `tailwind.config.ts`

```
export default {
    content: [`safelist`],
    safelist: [
        'right-0',
        'left-0',
        'w-1/2',
        'bg-secondary-500',
        'hover\\:bg-secondary-500',
        'hover:bg-contrast',
        'bg-darkgray-500',
        'hover:bg-darkgray-300',
        'bg-gray-300',
        'hover:bg-gray-900',
        'hover\\:text-white',
        {
            pattern: /text-black/,
            variants: ['hover'],
        },
    ],
    ...
```

I also tried the safelist stuff, with adding into content a file that contains the classes, it does not work ...

So it seems there's something broken, can't figure out what.

Comment: don't build class dynamically, that's not recommended by tailwind and will not work unless you whitelist every class

Comment: I wanted to go for whiteilisting every classes, but that does not even work @Lk77

Comment: Well, for a start, your content is wrong, it should be path to folders, like so : `content: [ './src/**/*']`. purgecss will look in there to see which classes are used

Comment: I would do a console.log of classes, most likely you did not whitelist every possible class, if you don't know all the classes in advance you will have to use a pattern

Comment: @Lk77 I'm using nuxt and nuxt/tailwind plugin, content is populated with the plugin. safelist file is just a file I tried to use for safelisting.
As for logging the classes, the only that work are the ones already present in the project. For all the others, it does fail. I focused on one, but none of them works

Comment: Are you sure the classes are actually applied correctly ? check the generated html to see if it match

Comment: They do are in the HTML page, and they're correctly applied. However, they're not in the generated styles :/

Comment: And when you build in dev you see the classes in the css file ?

Comment: @Lk77 No they ain't, that's somewhat purgeCSS not doing right the job ?

Comment: your classes should be in the dev build no matter what, it only removes the unused classes in production